# Elasticsearch Filter Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.5.2. I stored some products with a field named "allergic" and some others without this field. And the values of this field can be fish or milk or nuts etc. I want to make a query and to get as a result only products which doesn't have at all this field called "allergic" and to integrate this to an other aggregation query. I want to make just one query: first eliminate products which have "allergic" field and then execute the aggregation query of the second block.

How to integrate this :

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "missing" : { "field" : "allergic" }
        }
    }
}
```

to this aggregation query:

```
POST tes1/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs" : {
        "fruits" : {
            "filter" : {
                "query":{
                "query_string": {
                   "query": "Fruits",
                   "fields": [
                      "category"
                   ]
                }
            }},
            "aggs" : {
                "minprice": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "prix en €/kg": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ], "size":400
                    }
                }
            }
     }}   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the query part before the aggregation call. This will filter the results and then run aggregation on the resultset.

```
POST tes1/_search
{
    "_source": false, 
    "size": 1000, 
        "query": 
            { "constant_score" : {
                    "filter" : {
                        "missing" : { "field" : "allergic" }
                    }
                }
            },
    "aggs" : {
        "fruits" : {
            "filter" : {
                "query":{
                "query_string": {
                   "query": "Fruits",
                   "fields": [
                      "category"
                   ]
                }
            }},
            "aggs" : {
                "minprice": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "prix en €/kg": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ], "size":400
                    }
                }
            }
     }}   }
```

On a side note please consider upgrading ElasticSearch to the latest version as 1.x is no longer supported.

Comment: can you please read the question an other time? I edit it to add queries printed. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I put tried this: 
POST test1/_search
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "missing" : { "field" : "allergic" }
        }
    }
}

and I had an error

Comment: Modified my answer. Please try executing the above query.

Comment: It works ! I appreciate your help ! Thank you very much :)